# Root of unity is a unit in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, roots-of-unity

Wikipedia states that any root of unity in a ring is a unit(meaning it has a multiplicative inverse). Specifically if $r^n=1$, then $r^{n-1}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $r$.

But this is not true since in the ring of integers, except for $1$ and $-1$, any number is a root of unity, e.g. $5^0=1$, but there is no multiplicative inverse for the number $5$.

Am I understanding this definition correctly?

Comment: If your understanding were correct (it is not), the next stage would be to say $5^0=1 \implies 5^{1-1}=1 \implies 5^{1}\cdot5^{-1}=1\implies 5\cdot5^{-1}=1$ .  But you cannot say this, since $5^{-1} \not \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not. An element $r$ of a ring $R$ is a root of unity if $r^n=1$ for some $n\in\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. $\ \ \ \$

Comment: Which positive integer exponent would a real number have? For example if $5$ is a real number, how to show that it is a root of unity, since every real number has an inverse? Which exponent other than $0$ can we use?

Comment: You cannot show that $5$ is a root of unit in $\mathbb R$, since it isn't.

Comment: Is the definition wrong then or is the problem in reals that they are a field and this definition is only for rings?

Comment: The definition is **not** wrong. Your mistake consisted in thinking that $0\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, but since we cannot show every element of reals as a root of unity then the root of unity definition is for rings only? (since real numbers form a field)

Comment: Since $(\mathbb R,+\times)$ is a field, then in particular, it is a ring. And that Wikipedia article that you mentioned only says (correctly) that **if** an element of a ring is a root of unity **then** it is an unit. It does *not* say that every unit is a root of unity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for each element $r$ in a ring $R$, $r^0=1$.

However, you refer to the case that $r^n=1$ for some $n>0$.
Then, indeed, $$r\cdot r^{n-1} = 1 = r^{n-1}\cdot r$$ and so $r^{n-1}$ is the inverse of $r\ne 0$.